# Parse Javascript SDK doesn't work with Server URL

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I downloaded a demo project **Todos** of Javascript SDK from [Parse Tutorial Site](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiBuru9hPjPAhWDvRoKHdrYBqoQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.parse.com%2Ftutorials%2Ftodo-app-with-javascript&usg=AFQjCNE5LMXJvH53hiIL5NtJfbEFWrbgmg&sig2=Qj8tW9JrTZWWwOayunlMAA&bvm=bv.136593572,d.d2s&cad=rja). I tried with *www.parse.com*'s **applicationID** and **JavascriptKey** like below and worked

```
Parse.initialize("my-application-id",
               "my-javascript-key");
```

**but** When I tried linking it up with my self hosted parse (Which is working fine with ios) like below. It just doesn't give any error neither it logins nor signup.

```
Parse.initialize("MyAppID");
Parse.serverURL = 'https://www.MyParseURL.com/parse'
```

Comment: What version of the javascript sdk?

Comment: I'm using CDN and the SDK is parse-1.2.13
 <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>

Comment: that explains it, please update to the latest version (currently 1.9.2)

Comment: Is there any way I can debug this code in todo sample app ?

Comment: I want to debug todo.js file which contains all backbone code. How can I debug that code ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `Parse.serverURL` before calling `initialize`?